# How to dynamically change CSS class of an HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using JavaScript. I have a variable `var boolVal` that either evaluates to `true`/`false`. On my page, I have a `<div>` tag:

```
<div id='div1' class="redClass"></div>
```

Based on the value of `var boolVal`, I want to change the CSS class of the `<div>` tag to `blueClass`.

For example: present class makes `<div>` color red, then the new class should make the page blue at runtime without need for page refresh.

Can we achieve this in simple JavaScript? Can we use

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "MyClass";
```

or should we use `AddClass`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can add a CSS class based on `id` dynamically using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) API as follows:

```
document.getElementById('idOfElement').classList.add('newClassName');
```

Or the old way:

```
document.getElementById('idOfElement').className = 'newClassName';
// += to keep existing classes
```

---

Alternatively you can use other DOM query methods shown below to find elements. The last three return a collection so you'll have to iterate over it and apply the class to each element in the collection (similar to the example given below each).

- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

  ```
  elements.forEach(element => element.classList.add('newClassName'));
  ```
- [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

  ```
  Array.from(elements).forEach(element => element.classList.add('newName'));
  ```
- [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)

  ```
  Array.from(elements).forEach(element => element.classList.add('newName'));
  ```

---

In your case

```
var element = document.getElementById('div1');
if(boolVal)
   element.className= 'blueClass'; // += ' blueClass'; to keep existing classes
else
   element.className= 'redClass';
```

Answer (score 7):

First of all, [`AddClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) is not a pure Javascript method. It's related to jQuery.

[You can use Javascript for adding a class:](http://www.mzcart.com/javascript-how-to-addremove-css-class-from-a-dom-element/)

`setAttribute` and `className` both method are used to set class (class attribute), these method are not used to adding another class with existing one.

```
document.getElementById('div1').setAttribute( "class", "blueClass" );
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('div1').className="redClass";
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T2XG2/4/)

So if you want append a css class to an element, you can do it like this -

```
 document.getElementById('div1').setAttribute( "class", document.getElementById('div1').getAttribute('class') + " blueClass" );
```

OR

```
 document.getElementById('div1').className +=" redClass";
```

**Note**: Using this way, the same class can be added multiple times. It's only a trick to do this work using javascript, it's not a perfect solution

OR simply use jQuery to add class -

```
$("#div1").addClass("blueClass");
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T2XG2/7/)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = boolVal ? "redClass" : "blueClass";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
document.getElementById('div1').className='blueClass';
```

Comment: simply using `className=` will clear te other classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit inline styles on a DOM element like so (height in this example):

```
document.getElementById("element").style.height = height + "px";
```

Basic syntax is:

```
document.getElementById("div1").style.[style property] = [value];
```

Syntax for the style property can vary and might not be exactly what it is in a CSS file. For example, `background-color` in a CSS file would be 'backgroundColor` in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
    boolVal.onchange=function(){
                document.getElementById("MyElement").className = boolVal ? "redClass" : "blueClass";
    };
```