# how to create class attribute using dom in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am creating input tag with it's attributes by clicking on list item. Type, name and id are created successfully but it's not generating the class attribute.

```
var createInput = document.createElement("input");
        createInput.type = "text";
        createInput.name = text1;    
        createInput.id = text1;
        createInput.class = "abc";
```

Comment: `element.setAttribute("atrribute", "value");` Now, let's close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576927/how-to-dynamically-change-css-class-of-div-tag

Comment: It's actually `className` as `class` is a reserved word in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `class` property of a DOM Element is actually called `className`:

```
createInput.className = "abc";
```

Check out your browser's Debug Console (F12); it has auto-completion, so you can see what properties exist.