# How to activate the sidebar menu?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm using template adminpanel [chain-responsive-bootstrap3-admin-template](http://preview.themeforest.net/item/chain-responsive-bootstrap-3-admin-template/full_screen_preview/8539704?_ga=2.263146572.1142205989.1649314558-552971880.1648992208)
When a parent menu is active it should have a class of **active**.

When a parent menu with sub menus is active and also in a dropdown active state the class should be **parent active**.

How to make the class change dynamically?

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li><a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i> <span>Orders</span></a></li>
    <li class="parent"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span>Shop</span></a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="{{ route('category.index') }}">Categories</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route('product.index') }}">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route('product-attribute.index') }}">Attributes</a></li>
            <li><a href="">filters</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Uploads</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route('page.index') }}">Pages</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> <span>Marketing</span></a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="{{ route('stock.index') }}">Stocks</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ route('coupon.index') }}">Coupons</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span>Users and Roles</span></a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li><a href="{{ route('user.index') }}">Users</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Roles</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have googled "How to make the class change dynamically" and clicked the first result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576927/how-to-dynamically-change-css-class-of-an-html-tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically change CSS class of an HTML tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22576927/how-to-dynamically-change-css-class-of-an-html-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this.

Put this in your helper.

```
function activeMenu($uri = '')
{
    $active = '';
    if (Request::is(Request::segment(1) . '/' . $uri . '/*') || Request::is(Request::segment(1) . '/' . $uri) || Request::is($uri)) {
        $active = 'active';
    }
    return $active;
}
```

Write this code in your sidebar blade file.

```
<li class="{{ activeMenu('dashboard') }}">
   <a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}"><i class="fa fa-user-secret"></i> <span class="nav-label">Dashboard </span> </a>
</li>
```

Comment: this script only works for dashboard.

Comment: Yes for other you need to pass route for like this.

Comment: how to make a route for nested lists?